# JSON Array Parsing and Conversion to Java Types

Tags: json, org.json, arrays

I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm an intern working to develop a Blackberry App. So, I apologize in advance if I use any wrong terminology.

I make a HTTP Request for all of the friends of a particular user, and get a JSON response in this JSON array format.

> {"users": [{"username": "jonbob", "first_name": "Jon", "last_name": "Bob", "phone": "5555555555", "full_name": "Jon Bob", "id": 1}, {"username": "joesmith", "first_name": "Joe", "last_name": "Smith", "phone": "5555555555", "full_name": "Joe Smith", "id": 2}]}

I'm using the ***org.json*** parsing library. I'm trying to create a Blackberry list containing all of the User's Friends (like an address book).  But I am unsure how to acess the JSON Array with this org.json library.  I want to create a Java Array with only the full_names of all the friends.  How would you go about parsing this response to accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried.  Explain the specific part of the code that you had a problem with.  Explain what you thought it would do.  Explain what it appeared to do instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    /*
{
    "users": [
        {
            "username": "jonbob",
            "first_name": "Jon",
            "last_name": "Bob",
            "phone": "5555555555",
            "full_name": "Jon Bob",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "username": "joesmith",
            "first_name": "Joe",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "phone": "5555555555",
            "full_name": "Joe Smith",
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
}
     */
    String json = "{\"users\": [{\"username\": \"jonbob\", \"first_name\": \"Jon\", \"last_name\": \"Bob\", \"phone\": \"5555555555\", \"full_name\": \"Jon Bob\", \"id\": 1}, {\"username\": \"joesmith\", \"first_name\": \"Joe\", \"last_name\": \"Smith\", \"phone\": \"5555555555\", \"full_name\": \"Joe Smith\", \"id\": 2}]}";

    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray users = result.getJSONArray("users");
    int size = users.length();
    Friend[] friends = new Friend[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      JSONObject user = users.getJSONObject(i);
      friends[i] = new Friend(user.getString("first_name"), user.getString("last_name"));
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(friends));
    // output: [Jon Bob, Joe Smith]
  }
}

class Friend
{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  Friend (String f, String l) {firstName = f; lastName = l;}

  @Override
  public String toString() {return String.format("%s %s", firstName, lastName);}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at GSon this library is powerful for json and java manipulation.

```
List<Users> users= gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Users>>(){}.getType());
```

Here is the API doc.
http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: This would not work as suggested, because the input JSON data structure does not match the suggested target Java structure.  JSON object != Java List.